# Spring Boot: Multiple HSQLDB databases for one unit test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, hsqldb

I'm trying to create two separate HSQLDB databases for one unit test. The reason for this is that the real application will be performing different operations against different databases, so I want to test this functionality. However, I can't seem to get it to actually initialize two separate database instances. What I have is this:

```
new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .setName("DB1")
        .addScript("db/sql/create-db.sql")
        .addScript("db/sql/insert-data-db1.sql")
        .build();

    BasicDataSource dataSource1 = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource1.setUsername("TESTUSER");
    dataSource1.setPassword("Password1");
    dataSource1.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    dataSource1.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:DB1");

new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .generateUniqueName(true)
        .setName("DB2")
        .addScript("db/sql/create-db.sql")
        .addScript("db/sql/insert-data-db2.sql")
        .build();

BasicDataSource dataSource2 = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource2.setUsername("TESTUSER");
dataSource2.setPassword("Password1");
dataSource2.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
dataSource2.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:DB2");
```

It barks at the second database when it tries to run the create-db.sql script saying that all of the objects already exist. So, this is telling me that it's not running it into a separate instance. Is there a way of actually doing this?

Comment: Include the error(s)/log  in your question

Comment: Well, it just errors at the CREATE SCHEMA statement saying that the Object name already exists. So, it's running it into the same database rather than a new one like